# Calculating circularity

Tags: geometry

I have a circumference and the area of a shape and I want to calculate how circular it is.

I have an algorithm which I believe does this, but I don't understand the logic and I'd like to:

$$\frac{4\pi a}{c^2}$$

Could anyone break this down so I can follow? The reason for asking is that I would do it like this:

First I'd find the radius:

$$r = \sqrt{\frac{a}{\pi}}$$

Then calculate the circumference:

$$c = 2\pi r$$

Then I'd compare the calculated and actual circumferences somehow, although admittedly I'm not sure how because a simple difference wouldn't factor in the size of the shape.

Comment: You should also somehow incorporate the distribution of distances from each point on the shape to the center of it.

Comment: Is that necessary? Is that because a shape can sometimes have an area and circumference similar to that of a circle without being circular?

Comment: One error is that $r$ is not $\sqrt{\frac{a}{\pi}}$,  but $r = a\cdot \sqrt{\frac{1}{\pi}}$

Comment: Perhaps; you may come across some irregularities with convex polygons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a circle,

$$\frac{4\pi a}{c^2}=\frac{4\pi\pi r^2}{(2\pi r)^2}=1$$

and the *isoperimetric inequality* shows that this is the largest possible value for any shape. The farther this ratio from $1$, the more elongated/asymmetric/irregular the shape.

Comment: So I get $\pi r^2$ is the area but why is that multiplied by $4 \pi$ then divided by $(2 \pi r)^2$?

Comment: @user11406: to get $1$.

Answer (score 0):

A circle has the largest area $a$ among all shapes with the same circumference $c$. Hence $\displaystyle{4\pi a\over c^2}$ is $1$ for a circle and less than $1$ for a non-circular shape. That expression then gives a rough measure of circularity.

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain what $c^2$ and $4\pi a$ represents?

Comment: They are two homogeneous quantities (both have dimensions of area) which get the same value only if the shape is a circle.

Comment: Sorry, I had to think about it a bit. I see the relationship now.